# conda-forge::tqdm-4.19.4-py_0 - CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist

Tags: anaconda, conda, spacy

I'm trying to install SpaCy on Windows 7 using Conda and getting the following error:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy

tqdm-4.19.4-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 804.27 kB/s
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::tqdm-4.19.4-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Attempting to roll back.
```

Has anyone else go this and managed to resolve it? I would use Linux if I had a choice but sadly don't.

Answer (score 7):

Ok think I finally solved it.
Try doing running: `conda install tqdm` first.

Comment: Yip similar to @Marcin's comment. It worked for Spacy 2.0.3 too when I tested it now.

Answer (score 3):

I found that it helps to do a

conda update conda

before doing any other upgrade/install operations

Answer (score 1):

Run command :

```
conda config --add pinned_packages defaults::conda
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the problem was solved through the following solution

First:

`conda install tqdm -f`

then:

```
`conda update conda`
```